# Want to have a display table with sorting , searching, paging functionality on the html page using jquery

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, jquery-plugins

The following are the details of the issue I am facing:

**A] Technologies being used in the project:**

jQuery, Python, Django, google app engine.

**B] Question/ feature I am trying to add to the html page**

1] Want to add a table on the html page

2] Table should have multi column sorting functionality, if possible.

3] Table row colors should be slightly different from each other, so user can easily differentiate between them.

4] Search box on top of the table which allows the user to search the table.

5] Pagination in the table in case there are lot of rows to display

Can someone can provide to a well known library that is used for this purpose and will work with my server side code.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the DataTables plugin for jQuery. It will solve your problems

http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Thank you @Ancide for providing the link. Are there any sample projects with source code, that i can look at so i can implement the functionality correctly?

Comment: Thank you Ancide, i have got the basic datatable working in my html page. Now i am looking at feeding the datatable data from the python code, i will post a separate question for it.

Comment: The server-side examples provide PHP/Mysql code for feeding the datatable. It shouldn't be difficult to port that to Python and the Datastore - http://datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Answer (score 0):

[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) lets you use dynamic ordering and layout on different properties on client side and it's based on jQuery. You should definitely check it out.